# Finding even numbers using a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, user-input

I am trying to have the code listed below receive an int input from user, then find amount of even numbers in that int. I'm getting an error when I try to print the return... any help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class evenDigits {

public static int countEvenDigits(int number){
    if (number == 0)
        return 0;
    else{
        int lastDigit = number % 10;
        int result = countEvenDigits(number / 10);
        if (lastDigit % 2 == 0)
            return result + 1;
        else
            return result;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = keyboard.nextInt();

    countEvenDigits(number);

    System.out.println("There are " + result + " even digits in " + number);


}

}
```

Specifically, there is an error in this statement:

```
System.out.println("There are " + result + " even digits in " + number);
```

Comment: Specifically, there is an error in this statement:         System.out.println("There are " + result + " even digits in " + number);

Comment: You're not receiving the return value from `countEvenDigits` in main! You haven't even defined `result` in main.

Comment: Try `int result = countEvenDigits(number);` in your main. `result` is only declared in the method, not in your main.

Comment: No, they can be separate variables.

Answer (score 2):

In `main` you need to change:

```
countEvenDigits(number);
```

to:

```
int result = countEvenDigits(number);
```

Otherwise, you're accessing a nonexistent variable in your `println`